# Using angular with nested ng-repeat:

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat which I'd like to add the items on the array(album array), which works fine. I have colors array, which will add a different background-color to the card element of the album array. The result is incorrect, I've tried making the colors array an object on the same array still get the wrong result. Any help appreciated. Here is the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/alphalink/pen/mPQoGq/). Color array should loop back around to equal the arbitrary amount of albums in album array.

```
function MainController(albumSerivce, $filter) {
  'use strict';

  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.albums = [];
  ctrl.arrayColor = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
}
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: rgb(75, 175, 79);
  padding: 10px;
}
.red {
  background-color: rgb(255, 86, 34);
  padding: 10px;
}
.blue {
  background-color: rgb(61, 121, 182);
  padding: 10px;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
    <div class="albums-container" ng-repeat="album in ctrl.albums" ng-cloak>
      <div class="album {{color}}" ng-repeat="color in ctrl.arrayColor">
        <img class="image" ng-src="{{album.url}}" alt="" />
        <div class="title">{{album.title}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Update, I've also tried doing this. Couldn't exactly figure it out.

```html
<!-- Also tried doing different template with class included and using ng-if with modulus if this mightbe the better route? -->
<div ng-class="album green" ng-if="$index%">
  <img class="image" ng-src="{{album.url}}" alt="" />
  <div class="title">{{album.title}}</div>
</div>
<div ng-class="album red" ng-if="$index%">
  <img class="image" ng-src="{{album.url}}" alt="" />
  <div class="title">{{album.title}}</div>
</div>
<div ng-class="album blue" ng-if="$index%">
  <img class="image" ng-src="{{album.url}}" alt="" />
  <div class="title">{{album.title}}</div>
</div>
<div ng-class="album yellow" ng-if="$index%">
  <img class="image" ng-src="{{album.url}}" alt="" />
  <div class="title">{{album.title}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code pen is throwing an unexpected token error to me

Comment: @NarainMittal  Try it now.

Comment: What is supposed to happen when there are more albums than colors? Is it supposed to loop back around from the start of the colors array? And if so why not use something like nth-child type css selectors on your css classes

Comment: @PatrickEvans  Yes I could use css selectors, which is what I ended up doing. But I started with this and curious to find out if its possible/worth to do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not really want to iterate thru the the color array, you can just assign the class thru an expression. Let me know if [This CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaqZGZ) works for you.

```
<div class="album {{ctrl.arrayColor[$index%ctrl.arrayColor.length]}}" >
        <img class="image" ng-src="{{album.url}}" alt="" />
        <div class="title">{{album.title}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfecto, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to loop over the `colorArray` with a `ng-repeat` simply use the ngClass with an expression that will result in one of your color classes. To make it round-robin you can use the expression `albumIndex%colorArrayLength` (index [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) array length) to get the correct index.

```
ng-class="colorArray[$index%colorArray.length]"
```

`$index` being the auto filled variable angular will fill with the current index of an ng-repeat (in this case the index of the album array).

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("ctrl",function($scope){
  $scope.colorArray = ['green','red','blue','yellow'];
  $scope.albums =[{
    title:"Kitten 1",
    url:"https://placekitten.com/g/100/100"
  },
  {
    title:"Kitten 2",
    url:"https://placekitten.com/g/100/100"
  },
  {
    title:"Kitten 3",
    url:"https://placekitten.com/g/100/100"
  },
  {
    title:"Kitten 4",
    url:"https://placekitten.com/g/100/100"
  },
  {
    title:"Kitten 5",
    url:"https://placekitten.com/g/100/100"
  },
  {
    title:"Kitten 6",
    url:"https://placekitten.com/g/100/100"
  }];
});
```

```css
#container{ display:flex; }
.album { flex: 1 1 0; }
.album img { max-width: 100%; }
.green {
  background-color: rgb(75, 175, 79);
  padding: 10px;
}
.red {
  background-color: rgb(255, 86, 34);
  padding: 10px;
}
.blue {
  background-color: rgb(61, 121, 182);
  padding: 10px;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="album" ng-class="colorArray[$index%colorArray.length]" ng-repeat="album in albums">
    <img class="image" ng-src="{{album.url}}" alt="" />
    <div class="title">{{album.title}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for, just @narain answered first. Wish I could give them both the awarded answer.